# Issued a W9 for Rental Property (Computer Hardware)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property

As I understand, a W9 is typically issued for employment of a person. If a person from another company (for multiple company events) agrees to pay a rental fee of a hardware item owned by a person/corporation, for several occurrences are they   required to collect a W9 from the person/corporation?

(They rented $6,000-valued hardware from me a few times in 2017, at a day use rate of $400. This totaled to $1200, where they told me that anyone paid $600 or more requires a W9. I clarified that I was not paid for my work, and that this was just the property rental fee. I'm also afraid that this company is trying to phish my social security number.)

Comment: One solution to your SSN concern is to get an EIN for your business and report that to your customer: https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iss4

Comment: **W4** (and W2) is used for employment. W9 (and various 1099's) is used for _contracting_, which is not employment even if it seems similar to you, and for many other kinds of reportable income _and_ expense -- rentals like yours and royalties, bank/stock/bond/investment interest/dividends/gains, and many more. If this is the official form and not a substitute, have a look at the 'Purpose of Form' section at the bottom of the first page -- or get the official form from the IRS website and do so. However _if_ the payee is a corporation (no SSN ever) most reporting (and thus W9) is not required.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe a W9 is strictly required. But it is a convenient way for them to get the information they need. Since they paid you rental fees exceeding $600, they must issue a 1099-MISC. They have to get the information to do that somehow, and a W9 seems to be the best way.

See [this](https://markjkohler.com/1099-rules-for-business-owners/) for more details.

Comment: It seems Form 1099 C Misc seems the appropriate form. It doesn't mention rental property though - which is taken as different than rent (real estate)?